# Error on deleting subkey from registry using C#

Tags: c#, registry

I am trying to delete a subkey which my program earlier created but I am getting following error:

> Cannot delete a subkey tree because the subkey does not exist.

Here is the code:

```
RegistryKey reg;
reg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\MyCompany\\MyProgram",true);
if (reg != null)
{
    reg.DeleteSubKey("mysubkey");
    reg.Close();
}
```

I have verified in registry that subkey exists.

Comment: u sure that there is a subkey mysubkey inside "SOFTWARE\\MyCompany\\MyProgram"

Comment: Is your program running in 64bit or 32bit mode? Make sure that you are verifying by looking at the right hive.  32bit apps have their own hive under Wow6432Node

Comment: @Tung
I am on 32 bit Windows 7.

Comment: Make sure your program is running under same user account as the one you are using to check registry. Other tips: Try to read the value using reg.GetValue("...") before you delete which will make sure that key really exists. Also try to run your program as admin just to test this.